# AWS API Gateway body mapping template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Post method on API Gateway,
Following is my body mapping template -

```
#set($keys = [])
#foreach($key in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
  #set($success = $keys.add($key))
#end

#foreach($key in $input.params().headers.keySet())
  #if(!$keys.contains($key))
    #set($success = $keys.add($key))
  #end
#end

#foreach($key in $input.params().path.keySet())
  #if(!$keys.contains($key))
    #set($success = $keys.add($key))
  #end
#end

{
#foreach($key in $keys)
  "$key": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params($key))"#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
}

{
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "request_id" : "$context.requestId",
    "api_id" : "$context.apiId",
    "resource_path" : "$context.resourcePath",
    "resource_id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "http_method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "source_ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "account_id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api_key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user_arn" : "$context.identity.userArn"
}
```

**I want to receive Headers, requestBody and Source IP of the request caller**,
My Handler currently receives request in a POJO but currently it is not able to get either the requestBody, header or the source IP

Answer (score 1):

I believe the template you have doesn't work well since it looks like need to allocate some memory, but if you do something like this, it will work.

```
{
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "queryParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "pathParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "source_ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp"
}
```